# Visual basic : Generic GDI+ error when saving file

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

When I executed my program I created in visual basic. I got a GDI+ error when I tried to save an image from a picturebox.

If I run it on the PC, where I created the program(windows 10), I don't have any problems. When I run it on 2 different windows 7 PC's, I got the error.
The mapped networkdrive is the same ( Z:\ ) and writeable.

Here is the code:

```
 Private Sub SaveImage(ByVal pathToSaveTo As String)

    Try
        Using bmp As New Bitmap(Picimage.Image)
            bmp.Save(pathToSaveTo, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        ex.Message, "Error Saving Image File", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    End Try

End Sub
```

The button to start the action

```
  Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
    Dim testOutput As String
    testOutput = "Z:\" & naam & " " & Now.ToString("HH/mm/ss") & ".jpg"
    SaveImage(testOutput)
    nr.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: You get this exception whenever it has a problem writing the file.  It isn't good enough to tell you exactly what is wrong.  So put File.WriteAllText(pathToSaveTo, "test") before it and now you'll know.

Comment: You need to show the actual exception message in the question or we are just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

GDI is complaining about the filename you're using.

Here's the problem: `testOutput = "Z:\" & naam & " " & Now.ToString("HH/mm/ss") & ".jpg"`

You're generating a filename with slashes in the path. If those are meant to be directory names (a directory for each hour, minute and second respectively) then those directories need to ex that won't work as GDI will not create missing directories along a path for you. If the slashes are meant to be in the filename itself then it also won't work as slashes are not a valid filename character.

Change the slashes to underscores or hyphens or other characters allowed in filenames:

```
testOutput = "Z:\" & naam & " " & Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss") & ".jpg"
```